# Fetching Data from Database using Strings not IDs

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Whenever we save data to the database, there is always a corresponding ID which we use to fetch the data from that specific column.

```
sql_con.execute("SELECT FROM DBNAME WHERE ID = ?", id)
```

The above code only allows us to fetch data based from the ID. The problem is that the above code only accepts 1 supplied binding. In my database, I used sets of strings as the ID for each column, which means that the binding of my IDs are more than 1. And, those sets of strings have different bindings (or character count).

How do I modify the code in above, so I could input strings as my ID, preventing it from receiving the specific error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.
```

Thank you in advance. I use Python 3.xx and in-built module sqlite3. Database is in .db file format and is a disk-based database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my own question, by asking someone else. 
For you to resolve this problem with the bindings of the input, just simply convert the parameter into a tuple.

```
OLD CODE:
sql_con.execute("SELECT FROM DBNAME WHERE ID = ?", id)
```

INTO THIS...

```
NEW CODE:
sql_con.execute("SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE ID = ?", (id,))
```

Hope it helps.